# Showing who viewed the post ( user )

Tags: python, django, django-models, view

I am building a BlogApp and I build a feature, it counts the viewers. BUT i am trying to get who viewed the Post.

views.py

```
queryset = BlogPost.objects.annotate(num_views=Count('viewers')).order_by('-num_views')
datas = get_object_or_404(queryset,pk=pk)
if request.user.is_authenticated:
    created = BlogPost.viewers.through.objects.get_or_create(post=datas,user=request.user)
```

Below code counts the views of Post whenever i print `{{ datas.viewers }}`, BUT when i try to print `{{ datas.viewers.user.username }}` then, It doesn't show the viewed users

```
    class BlogPost(models.Model):
        viewers = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,related_name='viewed_posts',editable=False)
```

BUT i am trying to show `who viewed the BlogPost.

Any help would be Appreciated.

Thank You in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to iterate over the M2M data in the template, as

```
{% for viewer in datas.viewers.all %}
    {{ viewer }}
{% endfor %}
```